# How to pass data to mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I have a login form with a ng-href that opens an $mdDialog with a template showing a form that requires to show the login typed, if any, on the first login form.
Cannot manage to get that value. Not through locals or anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can you reproduce error and share a demo, it will be useful.

Comment: I can't, the project has too many dependencies to upload as it is. I can only say that I have this in the login page:
`<a ng-href="#" onclick="resetPasswordFunc(event,loginForm.userLogin.value)">¿Forgot password?</a>`

This function opens a $mdDialog that has a template:
`$mdDialog.show({
              templateUrl: 'templates/pages/security/resetPassword.html'`

This template has an input that should show the userLogin value the login form has. This shared data is not shared, evidently, and I don't know how to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Without a fiddle or something it is hard to test, but you can pass the data this way from your controller

Controller:

```
 $scope.openDialog = function (event,user) {
     ngDialog.open({
         data: {'event': event, 'user': user}
         controllerAs: 'vm',
         showClose: false,
         closeByDocument: false
        });
    };
```

Then you can get the data in the controller for your modal:

```
 $scope.data = $scope.ngDialogData.data;
 $scope.event = $scope.ngDialogData.event;
 $scope.user = $scope.ngDialogData.user;
```